# Sigma 20mm f/1.4 DG HSM Art vs. Voigtlander 21mm f/1.8 Ultron – which one is better for travel?

Tags: lens, comparison

I'm looking for a travelling lens that isn't too heavy and I have nailed down to choosing between these two.

I know the Sigma 20mm f/1.4 Art is super sharp and produces excellent images, but I was wondering whether the Voigtlander 21mm f/1.8 Ultron does the same?

The weight of the Sigma is over twice the weight of the Voigtlander.

Comment: What body/bodies are you using?

Comment: The camera body i am currently using is sony a7ii.

Comment: Are "super-sharp" and "produces excellent images" your only points of concern? What is an "excellent image" to you?

Answer (score 1):

Do you prefer the manual focus of the Voigtlander or the auto focus of the Sigma.  I would feel that would be the main concern.  They are both sharp and have little CA.  Although the Sigma has slightly less it is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a travel lens, I'd definitely take the Sigma F1.4 because it's an autofocus lens, which is a lot more convenient when taking pictures on the go. In addition it's 2/3 of a stop faster than the Voigtlander. It is indeed quite heavy at 950g, but assuming that would be your one lens it shouldn't be too noticeable.

If you provide us with the type of camera you're using we could provide some alternative suggestions for lenses you can take.

Answer (score 0):

For a travel 21mm, one might want to consider Color-Skopar. At f/3.5 it’s darker than Ultron, but much less to carry (size- and weight-wise).